# Functional Component and object values

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm working on a side project and i'm struggling to print out object values.

My code layout is as follows :

class based component

```
this.state = {
  itemDetails: []
};

axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/${itemId}?${API_KEY}`).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
  this.setState({ itemDetails: res.data })
});
```

returns this json data

[image]

Then I have a functional component

```
    const MovieDetails = (props) => {
  const arrayofKey = Object.values(props.itemDetails).map((r) => (
    <div>
      <a href='#t' className='item-name'>{r.original_title}</a>
    </div>
  ))
  return <div className='item-details'>{arrayofKey}</div>
}
```

Which is meant to return the value of original_title (Aquaman), however I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'original_title' of null"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you using `Object.values(props.itemDetails)` and iterating over it? From the looks of it in your map function `r` is going to be a string most of the time. You should just remove the map function altogether and use `props.itemDetails.original_title` directly.

Comment: I'm still learning JS so i'm a bit lost at times, i've removed the map function but still uncertain on the syntax..if isn't too much trouble would you mind posting a solution?

Comment: What are you expecting in terms of html for the output of the MovieDetails function?

Comment: @dotconnor just the original_title for now, I can figure out the rest

Comment: Shouldnt it be `Object.keys` not `Object.values` for array of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I've understood that what you are trying to achieve is just this code:

```
const MovieDetails = (props) => {
  return <div className='item-details'>
    <div>
      <a href='#t' className='item-name'>{props.itemDetails.original_title}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

For some unknown reasons you had redundant and wrong code there. I simply removed it and moved the div with title out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks man, I was basically fumbling with code from other components that achieved the same thing, though it was multiple objects in an array

Comment: @invrt Yes, I doubted if the json data represents an array of objects or just an object, then I've looked to the url `${ROOT_URL}/${itemId}` and inferred that it's the latter case!

Answer (score 2):

The following should suffice for just showing the title.

```
const MovieDetails = (props) => {
  const {itemDetails} = props; 
  return (
    <div className='item-details'>
      <a href='#t' className='item-name'>{itemDetails.original_title}</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You were 4 seconds quicker! But you also should always explain the solution, not just post code.

Comment: I've upvoted so you don't feel sad for the OP has selected my answer!